# I am using firebase with php & this is showing error following error

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

> Fatal error: Uncaught Kreait\Firebase\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: pakistandb-7130e-firebase-adminsdk-5dz83-7af18b5684.json can not be read: SplFileObject::__construct(pakistandb-7130e-firebase-adminsdk-5dz83-7af18b5684.json): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\pakistanPlants\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\ServiceAccount.php:126 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\pakistanPlants\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\ServiceAccount.php(74): Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile('pakistandb-7130...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\pakistanPlants\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Factory.php(128): Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount::fromValue('pakistandb-7130...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\pakistanPlants\fbconfig.php(24): Kreait\Firebase\Factory->withServiceAccount('pakistandb-7130...') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\pakistanPlants\admin\aaddblog.php(3): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #4 {main} Next Kreait\Firebase\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Invalid service account: pakistandb-7130e-firebase-adminsdk-5dz83-7af18b5684.json can not be read: SplFileObject::__construct(pakistandb-7130e-firebase-adminsdk-5dz83-7af18b5684.json): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\pakistanPlants\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\ServiceAccount.php:76 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\pakistanPlants\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Factory.php(128): Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount::fromValue('pakistandb-7130...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\pakistanPlants\fbconfig.php(24): Kreait\Firebase\Factory->withServiceAccount('pakistandb-7130...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\pakistanPlants\admin\aaddblog.php(3): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\pakistanPlants\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\ServiceAccount.php on line 76

I am totally clueless. I have tried everything but there is no fix for this error.

I want to insert data to firebase, but configuration is not working.

Here is my configuration:

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
// use Kreait\Firebase\Contract\Auth;

$factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount('pakistandb-7130e-firebase-adminsdk-5dz83-7af18b5684.json')

->withDatabaseUri('https://pakistandb-7130e-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/');

// $auth = $factory->createAuth();
$database = $factory->createDatabase();

?>
```

Comment: It cannot find `pakistandb-7130e-firebase-adminsdk-5dz83-7af18b5684.json`. Try using the full path to the file

Comment: as per [ask], please do not upload images of code, data or error messages. Please include everything as text, then it's much more usable for those who want to help you, and those who may be researching similar issues.

Comment: could you please tell me how to give path ??